# Stack Inline Multiple Django Models in Admin with indirect relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, orm, django-admin

I have the following three models

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    participant_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pin = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=4,
                            validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

class Teacher(models.Model):
    teacher_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    participant_id = models.OneToOneField(Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    compensation_id = models.OneToOneField(Compensation, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

class Compensation(models.Model):
    compensation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    wage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

To summarize,

- Participant has different types, one of them is Teacher (OneToOne
  relation).
- Teacher is one type of employee that is compensated and it's related (OneToOne relation) with Compensation Model

I want to create an admin form by stacking

- Participant
- Teacher
- Compensation

The problem:

I am using Participant as a primary model and stacking teacher to it. However, when I try to stack compensation to it, it apparently doesn't work due to missing foreign key relation between Participant and Compensation models.

An easy way out would be to have the fields of the Compensation model in the Teacher Model. However, it would create redundancy when I want to associate other types of Participants to it.

What could potentially be a solution to this? I am open to altering the model if it makes thing any easier or less complicated.

P.S. There are also other types of participants (Child, Parent) that I have not mentioned.

P.S.S. There are other fields in the above-mentioned models that I have not mentioned for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: There does not appear to be any reason not to just have the `wage` field on the `Teacher` model

Comment: There are (6) other fields in the Compensation model that I have ignored for the sake of simplicity. Also, there are other Models that have a OneToOne relation with the Compensation model.

Comment: Are all of the other OneToOneFields non-nullable too?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't follow your last suggestion. Is there a link or example that I can refer to?

Comment: You could define an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) that defines the compensation fields and subclass that instead of using the OneToOneFields. Then your relationships would be slightly simpler

Comment: This is definitely "A" way to do it and I will go ahead with this for now until I learn if there are any limitations to this other than column redundancy across multiple tables.